How to embed editor.md on a Moodle site?
I am trying to embed the following editor.md on Moodle, but it keeps loading.
You can go the the Moodle demo site, sign in as admin, open a course, add a page.
https://sandbox.moodledemo.net/

Then, copy and paste the following code into the page.

<link href="https://unpkg.com/editor.md/css/editormd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/editor.md/editormd.min.js"></script>

<div id="editor">
<textarea style="display: none;"></textarea>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var editor = editormd("editor", { 
            width: "100%", 
            height: "100%", 
            path: "https://unpkg.com/editor.md/lib/" 
        });
    });
</script>


It seems Moodle is not loadding Editor.md's dependencies via the path.
I don't know why.
Thanks for your help!
